# How to perform an assertion to verify an item is in a list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to figure out how to do an assertion to see if a number exists in a list.

So my list looks like:

```
data = [{'value': Decimal('4.21'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('84.73'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('70.62'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('15.00'), 'Type': 'credit'},
        {'value': Decimal('2.21'), 'Type': 'credit'},
        {'value': Decimal('4.21'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('84.73'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('70.62'), 'Type': 'sale'},
        {'value': Decimal('15.00'), 'Type': 'credit'},
        {'value': Decimal('2.21'), 'Type': 'credit'}]
```

Now I am trying to iterate through the list like:

```
for i in data:
    s = i['value']
    print(s)
    assert 2.21 in i['value'], "Value should be there"
```

I am somehow only getting the first number returned for "value" i.e. 4.21

Comment: Why do you think the string `"2.21"` should be "`in`" `Decimal(2.21)`?

Comment: Two major things going wrong here.  1. You're comparing a `str` to a `Decimal` which will never be equal.  2. You're doing an assert on every value, so the first value that doesn't equal will create an assertion error

Comment: You probably want something more like: `assert any(d['value'] == Decimal('2.21') for d in data)` to test if `any` dict in the list has this value.

Comment: yes this was a typo on my end. corrected it.

Comment: No you didn't, now you're comparing a floating point number to a Decimal, you need to do `assert Decimal('2.21')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems as other commenters pointed out. You compare the wrong data types (`str` against `Decimal`, or after your edit, `float` against `Decimal`) and you also terminate on first failure. You probably wanted to write:

```
assert Decimal('2.21') in (d["value"] for d in data)
```

This will extract the value of the `"value"` key from each sub-dictionary inside the list and search for `Decimal('2.21')` in them.

Comment: That seems clearer than the `any()` code I put in a comment.